# How to decode a base 64 string found in a JSON string to generate a UIImage?

Tags: json, swift, base64, decode, qr-code

I have pasted my code below. Essentially, I have been given an SDK, which has a JSON string that I then have to parse in order to get to what is a base64 string from which a QR Code is generated. I have been working on it, but the code errors out at the "let nsd = ..." line, with the message: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Any help of where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated. I am a novice when it comes to Swift and programming in general, so am finding this quite challenging. I am also don't think I am correctly converted the response into a JSON, as that is where it is first errorring out.

```
func qrCodeGenerator(payload : String) {

    guard let response = /response as a string from SDK/ else {return}


    /* convert response string to an NSData response, so as to convert to JSON in the code below */
    let nsd: NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: response, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!

    var jsonResponse = JSON.null

    do {

        /* convert the response to a json object */
        try jsonResponse = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: nsd as Data, options: []) as! JSON

        /* enter the result array, as the base64 string is contained there */
        var result = jsonResponse["result"][0]
        var resqr_64 = result["qr_b64"].stringValue

        print(resqr_64)

        var base64string = resqr_64

        /*The base64 string lies beyond the comma*/
        var base64image = String(base64string.split(separator: ",")[1]) as String

        var decodeString : NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: base64image, options: [])!
        var decodedimage: UIImage = UIImage(data: decodeString as Data)!

        QRCodeImageView.image = decodedimage
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: (dataDict["THUMBNAIL"] as? String)! , options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters{

            self.imgThumb.image = UIImage(data: decodedData)

        }
```

> try this code to get image from base64 string :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two serious issues in the code:

1) The response is most likely a regular JSON string (not base64 encoded), initializing base64 encoded `Data` from the string cannot work.
2) You cannot force cast the result of `JSONSerialization` to `JSON`, use the SwiftyJSON initializer.

Please try

```
func qrCodeGenerator(payload : String) {

    guard let response = /response as a string from SDK/ else {return}


    /* convert response string to an NSData response, so as to convert to JSON in the code below */
    let data = Data(response.utf8)

    do {

        /* convert the response to a json object */
        let jsonResponse = try JSON(data)

        /* enter the result array, as the base64 string is contained there */
        let result = jsonResponse["result"][0]
        let base64string = result["qr_b64"].stringValue

        print(base64string)

        /*The base64 string lies beyond the comma*/
        let base64image = String(base64string.split(separator: ",")[1])

        let decodeString = Data(base64Encoded: base64image)!
        let decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodeString)!

        QRCodeImageView.image = decodedimage
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Note: Aren't you concerned about the bunch of *`Variable 'xyz' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant`* warnings?

Comment: Thank you so, so much! That really helped.